# Prove that $v \in T_mSL(n) \iff \text{tr } v = 0$.

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, curves

Prove that $v \in T_mSL(n) \iff \text{tr } v = 0$.

I haven't idea how to prove that. I understand next steps:

1. $SL(n)$ - are the matrices $n\times n$ that have $\det = 1$
2. $T_mSL(n) = {W_m(SL(n))}/{\underset{m}{\sim}}$

Where $W_m(SL(n)) = \{\gamma \in C^{\infty}((\alpha,\beta), SL(n))\ |\ \gamma(0) = m, 0 \in (\alpha,\beta) \subset \mathbb{R}\}$

And $\gamma_1 \underset{m}{\sim} \gamma_2 \iff\exists$ coordinates $\xi$ that $(\xi \circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (\xi \circ \gamma_2)'(0)$

Next i can't understand how to do tasks like this

Comment: I have expend quite a bit my answer in order to provide some insight on the link between submersions and tangent spaces. It is a good exercise to check the unproved assumptions (well-definedness of maps) of my addendum.

Comment: This is not correct unless $m$ is the identity matrix. The tangent space at $m\in SL(n)$ is $\{mv: \text{tr}(v) = 0\} = \{A\in\mathscr M_{n\times n}: \text{tr}(m^{-1}A) = 0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Straight approach.** Direct computation from the definition.

By definition, one has:
$$\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})={\det}^{-1}(\{1\}).$$
Furthermore, for all $X\in\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, $M\mapsto XM$ is a diffeomorphism of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, hence it suffices to show that $\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a manifold in a neighbourhood of $I_n$ and one will have:
$$T_X\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})=XT_{I_n}\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R}).$$
Let us show that $\det\colon\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a submersion at $I_n$. It is a well-known result that:
$$\mathrm{d}_{I_n}\det\cdot H=\textrm{tr}(H)\tag{1}.$$
Hence, $\mathrm{d}_{I_n}\det$ is a submersion since it is a nonzero linear map with codomain of dimension $1$, $\textrm{tr}(I_n)=n$. Finally, $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a manifold of dimension $n^2-1$ and one has:
$$T_X\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})=X\ker(\mathrm{d}_{I_n}\det)=\{M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\textrm{ s.t. }\textrm{tr}(X^{-1}H)=0\}.$$

If you do not recall how to establish $(1)$ here is a sketch of a proof. For all $(i,j)\in\{1,\ldots,n\}^2$, let $E_{i,j}$ be the matrix with zero entries everywhere except the entry $(i,j)$ which is a $1$. Then, notice that:
$$\frac{\partial\det}{\partial E_{i,j}}(I_n):=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\det(I_n+tE_{i,j})-1}{t}=\delta_{i,j}.$$
Indeed, if $i\neq j$, then $\det(I_n+tE_{i,j})=1$ and $\det(I_n+tE_{i,i})=1+t$. Finally, one has:
$$\mathrm{d}_{I_n}\det\cdot H=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nh_{i,j}\frac{\partial\det}{\partial E_{i,j}}(I_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nh_{i,i}=\textrm{tr}(H).$$

---

**Addendum.** Submersions and tangent spaces.

I am going to expand a bit on the link between the tangent space and the kernel of the differential of a submersion, maybe it will shed some light.

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n$, let $v$ be a point of $M$ and let $(U,\Phi)$ be a chart of $M$ centered at $v$. The map $\ell\colon T_vM\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by:
$$\ell([c])=(\Phi\circ c)'(0),$$
where $[c]$ denotes the tangency class of a curve $c\colon]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[\rightarrow M$ going through $v$, is well-defined, namely the value $\ell([c])$ only depends of the tangency class of $c$ and is bijective. Indeed, it is injective by definition of the tangency relation and is surjective. If $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $t\mapsto\Phi^{-1}(tx)$ is a curve of $M$ going through $v$ such that:
$$\ell([c])=x.$$
Therefore, one can endow $T_vM$ with a structure of a $n$-dimensional vector space.

Now, let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a submersion at $v$, with $M\subseteq X$ and $n=\dim(X)-\dim(Y)$ such that:
$$M=f^{-1}(\{y\})$$
Now, notice that if $c\colon]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[\rightarrow M$ is a curve going through $v$, then:
$$f\circ c=y.$$
In particular, one has $\Phi\circ f\circ c=\Phi(y)$ and by differentiation, one gets:
$$\mathrm{d}_vf([c]):=(\Phi\circ f\circ c)'(0)=0.$$
namely $[c]\in\ker(\mathrm{d}_vf)$. Finally, we have establish that:
$$\ker(\mathrm{d}_vf)\subseteq T_vM.$$
Whence $T_vM=\ker(\mathrm{d}_vf)$, using the equality of dimension between the two vector spaces.

---

**Another approach.** The Cartan-Von Neumann theorem.

If you want to involve some machinery, you can always use the following:

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, then $G$ is a manifold whose tangent space at $I_n$ is:
>   $$\mathfrak{g}:=\{X\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\textrm{ s.t. }\forall t\in\mathbb{R},\exp(tX)\in G\}.$$

This is not a too hard result, the key point is observing that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a vector space which follows from $G$ being closed and the Lie-Trotter formula.

In our case, $\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is indeed a closed subgroup of $\textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, therefore:
$$T_{I_n}\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})=\{X\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\textrm{ s.t. }\forall t\in\mathbb{R},\det(\exp(tX))=1\}.$$
Using trigonalization over $\mathbb{C}$, one has:
$$\det\circ\exp=\exp\circ\textrm{tr}.$$
Finally, one gets:
$$\begin{align}T_{I_n}\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})&=\{X\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\textrm{ s.t. }\forall t\in\mathbb{R},\exp(t\textrm{tr}(X))=1\}\\&=\{X\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\textrm{ s.t. }\textrm{tr}(X)=0\}.\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you for your answering. Can you please explain some moments (can't understand your english(I have some problems with this)).

What you mean then use this : $\mathcal{M}_n$ and "submersion"?

Comment: @EugeneKorotkov Sure, $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a notation for matrices with real entries of size $n$ and a submersion is a smooth map between manifold whose differential is surjective at any point.