Why is the dimension of this square $n \times n$ matrix given as $n^2 - 1$?
There's a hole in my knowledge. I tried plugging it by reading more of Lee's book, but I couldn't easily find why the rank of this matrix is less than the number of elements squared. I'm afraid this knowledge may come from Linear Algebra, where I've forgotten an important property.
From Lee's Smooth Manifolds:

The set $\text{SL}(n, \mathbb R)$ of $n \times n$ real matrices with determinant equal to $1$ is called the special linear group of degree $n$. Because $\text{SL}(n, \mathbb R)$ is the kernel of the Lie group homomorphism $$\text{GL}(n, \mathbb R) \xrightarrow{\; \text{det} \;} \mathbb R^* $$ it is a properly embedded Lie subgroup. Because the determinant function is surjective, it is a smooth submersion
by the global rank theorem, so $\text{SL}(n, \mathbb R)$ has dimension $\boxed{n^2 - 1\;}$.

I tried reading about his constant rank theorem and submersions, but I couldn't find where he talks about the change in dimensions of a linear map. I'm vaguely aware of row space, column space, and the rank of linear maps, but what theorems and properties lead to a smooth submersion reducing the rank of the linear transformation by one?

$n^2$ variables, minus one constraint (on the determinant).

Can I have an article or book chapter reference that explains this in more thorough detail?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312003/dimension-of-sln-mathbbr-and-some-other-lie-groups

Where does it say anything about the rank of a matrix or a linear transformation?  $SL(n,\mathbb R)$ is a Lie group, not a matrix.  The individual elements of $SL(n,\mathbb R)$ are $n \times n$ matrices which are nonsingular, thus have rank $n$.
Determinant is not a linear map.

$\text{SL}(n, \mathbb R)$ is not a matrix.

Here's a sketch. You should fill in all of the details yourself.
A special case of the constant rank theorem states that if $k \le n$, $O \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, $f: O \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is smooth and surjective, and the rank of the Jacobian of $f$ (which, for each $x \in O$, is a linear map) is always maximal, then for any $c$ in the image of $f$, $f^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth submanifold of $O$ with dimension $n-k$.
Here, you should verify all of the details of the following: $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, the function $$\det: \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ is smooth and surjective, and the Jacobian of the function $\det$ is always maximal. So you can apply the theorem stated above.
Note that the word "rank" in "constant rank theorem" has absolutely nothing to do with the rank of the matrices in $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. It is referring to the rank of the Jacobian of a function or map.

One small correction: det is surjective onto $\Bbb R \backslash {0}$, not onto $\Bbb R$. (But you don’t need surjectivity for this argument anyway.)

@JackLee, thanks. And I did wonder why surjectivity was mentioned. But I decided that to say anything about this would only add to the confusion.

Reeposting this comment to fix the formatting errors. One small correction: det is surjective onto $\mathbb R \setminus {0}$, not onto $\mathbb R$. (But you don't need surjectivity for this argument anyway.)

Also the global rank theorem says something stronger. The way you phrased it, maximal rank is part of the assumption, but we only need to assume smooth constant rank and surjective; then we get that the map is a submersion (and level sets are smooth embedded submanifolds of codimension $k$).

@peek-a-boo, thanks for pointing that out.

You should mention the implicit assumption $n\geq k$. Otherwise maximal rank only implies an immersion, and level sets will then be of codimension $n$, i.e dimension $0$.

@peek-a-boo, thanks again. Change made.

By translations via  group multiplication in the manifold, at any point the group manifold  is a 1-1-image of the neighbourhood of the identity.
The tangent space at the identity is the Lie-algebra $\mathfrak {sl}(n,\mathbb R)$  yielding the linearized group elements $$\left(O_n(\phi_{ik})\right)_{nm} = \delta_{nm}+ \phi_{ik}\left( \delta_{in}-\delta_{mk} \right).$$ The one parameter subgroup along that direction is
$$e^{\phi_{ik}  \ \text{array}(\left( \delta_{in}-\delta_{mk} \right),n\times n)) )}= \text{array} \left( \delta_{nm} + (\cos(\phi_{ik}-1)(\delta_{in}+\delta{km}) + \sin(\phi_{ik}) \ \left( \delta_{in}-\delta_{mk} \right),n\times n)) ) \right)$$ with $det=1$ obviously by the $2\times 2$ block subdeterminant.
By $det$ as a group homomorphism, products of any length and factors have $det=1$
A basis of $\mathfrak {sl}(n,\mathbb R)$ is the set of real $n\times n$  matrices with all zeroes exepts a pair of $a_{ik}=-a_{ik}=\pm 1$ of dimension $n(n-1)$.
